# Furnace blower cycles off then on

Tags: hvac

Upon a call for heat my gas furnace (1997 Coleman/Evcon model DGAT056BDD counterflow furnace) blower normally delays coming on for 90 seconds. It consistently runs for a few minutes, stops for 8 seconds, then runs for the duration of the heating cycle and for 60 seconds thereafter (as per the settings on the control board). Does anyone have an idea what is causing this one-time 8 second off/on cycling of the blower during the heating cycle?

Comment: Welcome. Step one is usually telling us what device we're talking about. :) Please [revise your question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/158591/edit) with enough information to allow helpful answers. Also mention any error codes.

Comment: There was a [similar question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/156737/43874) a few weeks ago, but the asker never responded to comments.

Comment: To isherwood:  I mentioned the "device" is a gas furnace. If you are saying that is not specific enough, it is a 1997 Coleman/Evcon model DGAT056BDD counterflow furnace. There are no error codes.

Comment: Is this a new thing or has it always done this? Any changes made to the system like a new thermostat, smart thermostat, circuit board replacement, etc?